# Writing script arguments passed to an Excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript, arguments

I'm trying to write a script that will take arguments passed to it, and write them to an Excel file. I have four variables, one for the sheet, row, column and value. for simplicity I'm using Command Prompt for testing, and passing a series of two's, so on Sheet 2, Row 2, Column B, write "2".

```
Dim DCRT '(0)=Day/Sheet, (1)=Column, (2)=Row, (3)=Time
Set DCRT = WScript.Arguments

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsx")
objexcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Sheets(DCRT(0)).Cells(DCRT(1), DCRT(2)).Value = DCRT(3)
```

The error I get is

> (7, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Subscript out of range"

If I echo the arguments, I get back 2 2 2 2, so I know it is getting passed.

To try and get around this, I came up with

```
Dim SHEET, COLUMN, ROW, VALUE
SHEET = DCRT(0)
COLUMN = DCRT(1)
ROW = DCRT(2)
VALUE = DCRT(3)
```

and

```
objExcel.sheets(SHEET).Cells(COLUMN, ROW).Value = VALUE
```

This also throws a "Subscript out of range" error.

If I set the `SHEET`, `COLUMN`, `ROW` and `VALUE` variables to "2" everything runs fine. and I get a "2" in my spreadsheet.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What are the values of DCRT(0), DCRT(1),DCRT(2),DCRT(3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Excel right now, but I suspect that the issue is caused by a type conflict. The `Arguments` elements are strings, but should be integers if you want to access collection items by index rather than name.

Change

```
objExcel.sheets(DCRT(0)).Cells(DCRT(1), DCRT(2)).Value = DCRT(3)
```

into

```
objExcel.sheets(CLng(DCRT(0))).Cells(CLng(DCRT(1)), CLng(DCRT(2))).Value = CLng(DCRT(3))
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks.
I've been having a really hard time finding VBScript documentation.
I imagine that 'CLng' is somehow "Change Language"?

Comment: I don't consider the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) that hard to find. The [Windows Help file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764) is also handy to have around. As for [`CLng`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), that means "Convert to Long (integer)".